# satisfying two auto layout constraints programmatically - Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, constraints

I want to set a `UIButton` with autoLayout constraints:

Basically I want the height to be the multiplier of the container view height:

```
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.43).isActive = true
```

and if the height doesn't reach the constant of 44 I want to set it to 44, I added this:

```
button.heightAnchor(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44).isActive = true
```

Obviously programmatically setting 2 constraints like this causes a conflict, is there a way for programmatically accomplishing these 2 prerequisites without causing a warning?

Comment: 'and if the height doesn't reach a certain constant I want to set it to a numerical constant, I added this' -- please explain this

Comment: I edited it with the correct numerical constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set lower priority for the "ratio" constraint

```swift
let constraint = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.43)
constraint.priority = .defaultHigh
constraint.isActive = true
```

if the engine still have troubles with figuring out the layout, you can try different priority value.

[UILayoutPriority documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutpriority)

Answer (score 1):

You either set a low priority of

```
let con = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.43)
con.layoutPriority //////////////
con.isActive = true
```

or calculate it yourself mathematically and decide with if statement